# Passing in const vectors in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a project utilizing a 3rd party library that has created a method which requires the following parameter to be passed in:  `const std::vector< const Image *>`
When trying to create a `std::vector< Image * >` which allows flexibility in generating items into the vector I could not pass in this type to the method.  I assumed that VC++ 2010 would show the method as to intention via the argument type, but it seems to need that parameter type declaration in order to pass it in.  Here is what I ended up using that does compile:

```
const Image *SRImages1 = &SRImages[0];
const Image *SRImages2 = &SRImages[1];
const std::vector< const Image *> SRImageVector(&SRImages1, &SRImages2);

tungsten::vision::SuperResolution::ResultEnum r = SR.enhance( &resultImage, SRImageVector, referenceImageIndex, referenceImageROI, interlaced, asynchronous, listener);
```

Of course this is very restrictive and I would like to be able to generated items dynamically into the vector by using a push_back operator.

Why is MS VC++ requiring this and how can I work within these limits to create a vector that I can manipulate?

**Edit:** Copied from OP's comment:

Here is the signature from the .h file:

```
ResultEnum enhance( Image *result,
                    const std::vector<const Image*> &images,
                    unsigned int referenceImageIndex,
                    Rectangle referenceImageROI,
                    bool interlaced,
                    bool asynchronous,
                    SuperResolutionListener *listener );
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you would like to have, I can't really see the problem with the current code.

Comment: Please show the signatur of the lib function. I think the argument is of type `const std::vector< const Image *>&`

Comment: Here is the code I would like to use:

Comment: Here is the signature from the .h file:                  ResultEnum enhance(
                        Image *result,
                        const std::vector<const Image*> &images,
                        unsigned int referenceImageIndex,
                        Rectangle referenceImageROI,
                        bool interlaced,
                        bool asynchronous,
                        SuperResolutionListener *listener);

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comment, the actual parameter appears to be

```
const std::vector< const Image *>&
```

In other words, it's taking the `vector` by const reference.  This means that you can simply construct a non-const vector using `push_back`, and pass that into `enhance`.  e.g.

```
const Image *SRImages1 = &SRImages[0];
const Image *SRImages2 = &SRImages[1];
std::vector< const Image *> SRImageVector(&SRImages1, &SRImages2);  // Iteration constructor.
SRImageVector.push_pack(new Image);  // Example only - beware memory leak


tungsten::vision::SuperResolution::ResultEnum r = SR.enhance( &resultImage,
                                                              SRImageVector,
                                                              referenceImageIndex,
                                                              referenceImageROI,
                                                              interlaced,
                                                              asynchronous,
                                                              listener );
```